# Generating a linear system for popularity calculation

Tags: matlab, math

This is an half mathematical half computer science question. I am working on matlab on a mathematical problem.
I want to generate a linear system for the calculation of popularity of people (a vector `x`) in a generic social network, given a simple matrix of friendship `F`. If user 1 and user 2 are friends, `F(1,2)=1` but also `F(2,1)=1` (the friendship is bidirectional). To transform this problem in a linear system I need that the popularity value of a person (`x(i)`) and the popularity of all his friends (`∀x(j) | F(i,j)=1 and j≠i`) are linearly dependent. So I wrote this simple formula

```
x(j) = sum(x(i) x n(i) x F(i,j))  ∀i≠j
```

where `n(i)` is the number of friends of i.

For `size(x)=3` the system is something like this

```
-x(1) + f(1,2) n(2) x(2) + f(1,3) n(3) = 0 
f(2,1) n(1) x(1) - x(2) + f(1,3) n(3) x(3) = 0 
f(3,1) n(1) x(1) + f(1,2) n(2) x(2) - x(3) = 0
```

With this specific formula there are two problems:

1. With no constant term, the solution found is `x(i)=0 ∀i`
2. I need positive values of popularity, but this approach gave also some negative (and correct!) results.

So I need a formula that doesn't have this two problems. The formula can be chosen arbitrarily because the problem is totally defined by me. It must take account of friendship relations and number of friends in a linear combination (necessary to get a linear system), but also be positive.
Here the code of the generation and resolution of the system

```
n=10;
F=triu(randi([0,1],n));
F=F-diag(diag(F));
F=F+F';
N=(sum(F))';
A=ones(n);

for i=1:n
    A(:,i)=diag(N)*F(:,i);
end
A=A-eye(n);
b=zeros(n,1);
x=A\b
```

Comment: 2) constrained minimization (fmincon). As a hint: note that your "question" has no question, nor code that you are using. Try to add both

Comment: ...Also you never told us what `n(i)` is, and if the negative values are correct then you're asking **us** to come up with a new formula to define your metric which is only positive? /:)

Comment: Well I forgot to insert my question when I was trying to be enough clear. I need a new formula that can generate a linear system of the explained kind but that gives only positive popularity values.